# Analytical solution for 2D Advection-diffusion equation considering Dirichlet/Neumann BC

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, fourier-series, elliptic-equations

I am looking for the analytical solution of 2D Advection-diffusion equation on a rectangular domain $\Omega= (0, a)\times(0, b)$ considering:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& C_t +\lambda C + \nabla\cdot\mathbf{u}C  - \nabla\cdot(\mathbf{D} \nabla C) = 0, \text{ for } (x, y, t) \in \Omega \times \mathbb{R^*_+} , \\
& C(x,y,t=0) = \rho(x,y) = f(x)g(y), \text{ for } (x,y) \in \Omega,\\
& f(x) =\left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
1, &x \in [x_0,x_1]\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{array} \right.
g(y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl}
1, &y \in [y_0,y_1]\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}\\
\end{array} \right. \\
& C(x=0,y,t) = C(x=a,y,t) =  0, t \in \mathbb{R^*_+},\\
& \partial_y C(x,y=0,t) = \partial_y C(x,y=b,t) =  0, t \in \mathbb{R^*_+},\\
& \mathbf{u}=(u_x=0,u_y=cst>0)
\label{problem}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The objective of my post is to verify that the solution calculated with a numerical solver (OpenFOAM...) comply with the analytical solution.

I have successfully managed to find the solution for pure Dirichlet BC and verified the compliance between the numerical solver, but I have some "doubts" when I introduce the Neumann BC $\partial_y C(x,y=0,t) = \partial_y C(x,y=b,t) =  0$.

My very first question is: is the problem well-posed? I had a look on related topic and I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1355290/is-the-parabolic-heat-equation-with-pure-neumann-conditions-well-posed). However my problem is a bit different than the one described and I don't really know if the answer is applicable here. My concern is that since $C(x,y=0,t) = C(x,y=b,t) \neq  0$, intuitively, we expect "mass injection" at the $C(x,y=0,t)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R^*_+}$. Having tried to solve the problem with OpenFOAM, I get quickly a "diverging solution" where the mass is increasing seemingly indefinitely. Having tried with another solver the solution does not diverge, despite the "mass injection". I would like to decide between the solvers.

My second question holds only if the problem is well-posed. In order to find the solution I used the classical separation of variables method $C(x,y,t)=X(x)Y(y)T(t)$. When I want to solve $Y(y)$, I consider that the form of the solution is:
\begin{equation}
Y(y)=\exp{(\gamma y)}\big(A\cos{(\eta y)}+B\sin{(\eta y)}\big),
\end{equation}
where $\gamma\pm i\eta$ are the complex solutions of the corresponding characteristic polynomial:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\gamma\pm i\eta  & =\frac{-u_x}{-2D_x}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{-2D_x}, \\
     & =\frac{u_x}{2D_x}\pm i\frac{\sqrt{|\Delta|}}{2D_x}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
With the the previously defined BC, I have to solve the following system:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\partial_yY(0)=\exp{(\gamma 0)}\big((\gamma A+\eta B)\cos{(\eta 0)}+(\gamma B-\eta A)\sin{(\eta 0)}\big) & = 0,\\
\partial_yY(b)=\exp{(\gamma b)}\big((\gamma A+\eta B)\cos{(\eta b)}+(\gamma B-\eta A)\sin{(\eta b)}\big) & = 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The solutions of the previous system are:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A = -\frac{\eta B}{\gamma },\\
B\bigg(\gamma+\frac{\eta^2}{\gamma}\bigg)\sin{(\eta b)} & = 0, \gamma \neq 0.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
In order to satisfy the second equation of the previous system I choose (considering a Fourier series to come):
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\eta &= \eta(m) = \eta_m = \frac{m\pi}{b},\\
B & = B(m)=B_m,~m\in\mathbb{N^*}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The form of the solutions is:
\begin{equation}
Y_0(y)= B_m\exp{(\gamma y)}\bigg(-\frac{\eta_m}{\gamma }\cos{(\eta_m y)}+\sin{(\eta_m y)}\bigg),~m\in\mathbb{N^*}, \gamma \neq 0.
\end{equation}

I have a question at this stage, unlike for the Dirichlet BC solution, I notice that $\gamma\neq0$ which means that the solution does not stand anymore if $u_y=0$. How should I interpret this considering the concern express in my first question?

Pursuing with the normalization I have to calculate the scalar product of two eigenfunctions which leads formally to:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
N^2_{jk} & = \int_0^b \bigg(-\frac{j\pi}{b\gamma}\cos{(\frac{j\pi y}{b})}+\sin{(\frac{j\pi y}{b})}\bigg) \bigg(-\frac{k\pi}{b\gamma }\cos{(\frac{k\pi y}{b})}+\sin{(\frac{k\pi y}{b})}\bigg) dy,\\
N^2_{jk} & = \bigg(\frac{jk\pi^2}{2b\gamma^2} + \frac{b}{2}\bigg)\delta_{jk},\\
N_{j=k} & = \sqrt{\frac{j^2\pi^2}{2b\gamma^2} + \frac{b}{2}}.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I notice that norm won't be constant with regard to $m$ (or $j,k$) for the Fourier series like with the Dirichlet BC. Again, How should I interpret this?

$B_m$ Fourier series coefficients are determined through:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
B_m&=\frac{1}{N_{j=k=m}}\int_{0}^b \exp{(-\gamma y)}g(y)\bigg(-\frac{\eta_m}{\gamma }\cos{(\eta_m y)}+\sin{(\eta_m y)}\bigg)d y,\\
B_m & = \bigg(\frac{m^2\pi^2}{2b\gamma^2} + \frac{b}{2}\bigg)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\bigg[ -\frac{1}{\gamma}\exp(-\gamma y)\sin{(\eta_m y)}\bigg]_{y_0}^{y_1},
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Finally, when I try to calculate the solution it doesn't seem to give consistent results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case this may help some people, after trials and errors I finally figured out that the normalization factor $N^2_m$ had to be applied...

If I trust the calculation, I guess I can also conclude that the problem is well-posed...

Best regards,

[image: Example of time evolution of 2D advection-diffusion analytical solution with Dirichlet(X)/Neumann(Y) BC]